# Exchange 2010 - Use office-field as condition in E-Mail address policy

Tags: exchange-2010

I need to use the AD office-field as condition for an E-mail address policy.

I googled it, but unfortunately I found no solutions.

Do you have an idea how to solve this?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Greetings
Löwä Cent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've found the solution by myself.

The key is the Exchange Management Shell.
With the following prompt you can filter by any AD-Field you want:

```
New-EmailAddressPolicy -Name 'PolicyName' -EnabledEmailAddressTemplates 'SMTP:YourAddressTemplate@your.domain' -RecipientFilter {((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and ((Office -like '1stOffice') -or (Office -like '2ndOffice') -or (Office -like '3rdOffice')))}
```

If you want to filter by another AD-field, change "Office" to whatever field you want to filter.

I hope this will help some people in the future.